# How do I inject windows username into new java.io.FileInputStream?

Tags: java, java-io

I would like to inject the windows username into the URL location which is taken by the input stream as a string. It needs to be one continuous String, and I can't figure out how to insert it. What is the proper way to do this? This is how it is set up.

```
private String currUser = System.getenv("USERNAME");
fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\currUser\\db_creds.properties");
```

I need the `currUser` in the String to recognize the username.

Comment: Can you not just use a string that contains c:\\users\\ then + currUser + \\db_creds.properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String.replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
"C:\\Users\\currUser\\db_creds.properties".replace("currUser",currUser );
```

After clarification the following versions should also work:

```
fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\"+currUser+"\\db_creds.properties");
```

My favorite is the following, because it is OS independent:

```
 fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/db_creds.properties");
```

Or reading it from a property file.

Also I would suggest to use `/` instead of `\\`.

Comment: Works. thank you.. idk why i couldn't find this easy replacement... ( I have never had to use it before... always just use the " ", + -- +," "

Comment: @JasonD the other version wouldn't work if you have commas in it like you do in this comment

Comment: @JasonD A simple concatination should also work. But i assumed the pathname was a predefined "template" string

Comment: might be why it wouldnt work then... i'm not sure why i insisted on the commas...

Comment: nope, i setup the pathname for my c drive, i need many people to be able to access the db through their own creds.

Comment: Then the easiest way is : `"C:\\Users\\"+currUser+"\\db_creds.properties"`, or better put it into a properties file and read it from user.home

Comment: I realize `/` is tolerated on Windows sytems, but why would one go out of one’s way to use it, when it’s not the native file separator?

Comment: @VGR Because Java is a portable language and the could should be runable on different OS too. Also `/` is better readable as `\\\`

Comment: If that’s a concern, wouldn’t `new FileInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "db_creds.properties"))` make more sense?  Or, of course, `Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "db_creds.properties"))`.

Comment: @VGR That's why i suggested it

Answer (score 2):

```
private String currUser = System.getProperty("user.name");
fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\" + currUser + "\\db_creds.properties");
```

`System.getenv` should be working too, for what it's worth.

If this doesn't work, please edit your question to include an error message or a stack trace of what the problem is.

Comment: tried this way it doesn't like the +s inside the argument i am not sure why
this is the way that i have always done this... made no sense why it wouldnt work